How do I store the date/time when adding or updating a row inside of an ACF Pro Repeater field?
I’ve created a CPT for “Projects” and I’m using a repeater field to track daily “Project Updates”. Each day, a new row is added using the repeater and the relevant information is entered for that particular update. I’m trying to find a way to capture the date/time that the repeater row (“update”) is added or modified so that I can output this information on the frontend.
Is there a relatively simple way to accomplish this task using the ACF repeater?
I know that I can make this work by creating another CPT for the “Project Updates” and use a relationship to tie them together, but I would prefer to keep the updates right in the Project post. This avoids having to switch back and forth between post types and helps avoid tying an update to the wrong project.

Simple: Add a date and time field to the repeater row, that the user adding a new row is required to set correctly.
Advanced: Add a date and time field to the repeater row, that is readonly, and is updated on post save (the acf/save_post action) by comparing the repeater rows against the current rows in the database, and set the date and time field's value programmatically for any new rows (untested):
/**
 * Priority of five so that it runs before new values are saved.
 */
add_action( 'acf/save_post', static function ( $post_id ) : void {
    if ( 'project' !== get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $current = get_field( 'repeater', $post_id );
    $new     = $_POST['repeater']; // This is not correct.

    if ( $current === $new ) {
        return;
    }

    // Perform logic to compare entries in $new to entries in $current.
}, 5 );

